# Adding cell text to an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've been trying to research this for a while now. I'm trying to write a function that will find the last populated row in column B (Starting at B9), and add the string values in column B into an array.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks everyone.

```
Option Explicit
Function locationSum2(location) As Integer

Dim arrayLength As Integer
arrayLength = LastRowInColumn(2) - 9

Dim arrayPosition As Integer

Dim locationColumn() As String
ReDim locationColumn(0 To arrayLength) As String

Dim celltext As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To i = arrayLength
    celltext = Cells((9 + i), 2).Text
   locationColumn(i) = celltext
Next i

For arrayPosition = 0 To arrayPosition = UBound(locationColumn)
    If location = locationColumn(arrayPosition) Then
        locationSum2 = locationSum2 + Cells(arrayPosition + 9, 11).Value
    End If
Next arrayPosition

locationSum2 = locationSum2

End Function
```

Following a comment, I also chopped the code way down to basically just a loop that check the argument against everything in column B instead of making an array.

```
Option Explicit
Function locationSum2(location) As Integer

Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = LastRowInColumn(2)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 9 To i = LastRow
    If location = Cells(i, 2).Text Then
        locationSum2 = locationSum2 + Cells(i, 11).Value
    End If
Next i

locationSum2 = locationSum2
```

For whatever reason, it still doesn't seem to be reading Column B properly. It's returning a value of 0 so it doesn't seem to be finding a match.

Comment: The wording of the question is a bit difficult to understand. 
corresponding integer = count? or is it a hash/some value from a table? - seems like more words for less clarity lol

Comment: I tend to do that, sorry. I cut the question down to try and get at the core issue, also added some stuff as a follow up to the other response.

Comment: Why are you adding the cells to an array? If your sole purpose is to check against a value, why not iterate through the cells and update the cell in the new column when there is a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've setup the for loops incorrectly.

```
For i = 9 To i = LastRow
```

should be

```
For i = 9 To LastRow
```

I'm not sure if that is you're only problem, but lets start there

Comment: It seems to have indeed been the only problem. Thank you good sir, I was hoping it was just a clerical error on my part.

Comment: Nice, short solution. gl